# How to place parameters at the start of url in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

am trying to build a simple POS system than can be accessed by different users in different businesses what I want to achieve is that the site is hosted at one place for all the businesses but they access it through urls with unique id of the business.

So like github loads a user profile through

```
 https://github.com/USERNAME
```

I would like my system to be accesses as

```
 https://example.com/BUSINESS_ID
```

and the other urls will follow i.e

```
https://example.com/BUSINESS_ID/menu
https://example.com/BUSINESS_ID/pos
https://example.com/BUSINESS_ID/supplies
```

how can I achieve this with react.

I have tried using

```
`/:business_id/menu`
```

and so on in my urls but the page just loads blank
Any ideas and suggestions of the best way to achieve this with react will be highly appreciated

**This is how I am routing**

in index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/:business_id/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/" component={dashboard} exact />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

in app.js

```
  <Route path="/:business_id/"
    render={({ match: { url } }) => (
         <>
           <Route path={`${url}`} component={menu} exact />
             <Route path={`${url}orders`} component={orders} />
             <Route path={`${url}menu`} component={menu} />
         </>
     )}
  />
```

Everything was working fine before I introduces the parameter **business_id**

Comment: You use react-router correct? What version?

Comment: You have to add some base url... for detailed answer add some routing code here

Comment: I am using react-router-dom `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"` as in my package.json

Comment: @SoftwareEnggUmar, alright, let me edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App.js try using the `react-router` `match.path` instead of `match.url` props.

From the React docs:

- `path` - (string) The path pattern used to match. Useful for building
  nested < Route >s
- `url` - (string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful
  for building nested < Link >s

Consider the route `/:businessId`. `match.path` would be `/:businessId` while `match.url` would have the `:businessId` value filled in, e.g. `/3423ui67x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Router path={"example.com/:business_id"} exact="true"/>
```

will help you send the required id to example.com like example.com/3